# Angular 2 - How to use build-in pipe inside custom pipe

Tags: angular, angular-pipe, angular2-custom-pipes

I want to make a custom currency pipe using the built-in currency pipe. The way I want to use is `{{ anyNumber | customCurrency }}.` Then inside my customCurrency pipe, I want to use built-in currency pipe. I can decide the parameters to currency pipe based on some logic and don't want to specify locale and other parameters everywhere like `{{anyNumber | currency:'USD':false:'1:0-0'}}`.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'customCurrency'
})
export class CustomCurrencyPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
      const defaultLocale = 'USD';
      const showSymbol = false;

      ......some logic here......      

      //HOW TO USE CURRENCY PIPE HERE?

 }

}
```

Comment: Either use dependency injection or, as the currency pipe is stateless, just `new` one up (you can `@Inject(LOCALE_ID)` to pass as its constructor argument).

Answer (score 1):

You should inject the built-in pipe into your custom pipe than you can call it's transform method with your default values

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'customCurrency'
})
export class CustomCurrencyPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(public currencyPipe: CurrencyPipe) {
  }

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
      const currencyCode = 'USD';
      const showSymbol = false;
      return currencyPipe.transform(value, currencyCode, showSymbol);
 }

}
```

Comment: @tuliomarchetto actually `extend` is not general/good solution - especially when you want to use more pipes inside one pipe.